# Process builder-only on first time field update action should work

Tags: workflow, process-builder, validation-rule

In process builder- i need to give the criteria/condition only on first time field gets edited,the action should fire.my scenario is- record will be created and after some time user will edit one field at that time action should execute not everytime users edits(only on first edits),i have tried the below formula,not working

```
AND(ISNEW(),ISCHANGED(Field))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in a Process Builder context, you'd need to have a second field on the object (which can be hidden from the page layout). Call it `Has_Been_Edited__c`, a checkbox. Then your Process can check for

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Field__c), NOT(Has_Been_Edited__c))
```

It should then fire your action and also update `Has_Been_Edited__c` to `true`.

`ISNEW()` checks whether the object itself is newly created.

Comment: Darn! that was quick, I was just about to post. :P

Comment: i need to create a new field called 'has_been_edited' ryt?how it will be updated?,did i need to do workflow for updation

Comment: You stated that you are using Process Builder. As in the answer above, your process should update that field.

Comment: my action is to create new record.then how can i uptade this field?

Comment: Processes can execute multiple actions.

Comment: working fine super

Answer (score 0):

Work Around
In Formula evaluates to true

**Object_API_Name__c.CreatedDate <> Object_API_Name__c.LastModifiedDate**

So, If both are equal then process is running for newly created record.
else
process will run for updated record.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This could possibly work in some orgs, depending on the object and the company's processes. However, if there are other background processes in the org which could possibly modify this record, and if the requirement is that a User is allowed to edit this particular field once, and if the requirement allows for modification of other fields on the record prior to allowing the editing of this particular field one time, then this workaround solution will not work.